# "Placeholder" Binding In StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` that gets its `Style` from a static resource. For an example, I have an `ObservableCollection` of a custom object in my `MainWindowViewModel`. This object contains a few properties, including `MyCustomObjectProperty`. The `MainWindowViewModel` also has an `ICommand`, `MyCommandOne`.

My style (with some pieces cut out, for simplicity):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <!--(Removed extra Setters)-->
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyCommandOne,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=MyCustomObjectProperty}">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <!--(Styling)-->
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Creating the `ListView`:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObservableCollection}"
                  Style="{StaticResource MyListViewStyle}"
                  Margin="5"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Background="LightGray"
                  />
```

This code works. When I click a button in the `ListView`, `MyCommandOne` is executed with the parameter from the custom object that is represented by the clicked list view item.

My question here: is there a way to replace `DataContext.MyCommandOne, RelativeSource...` with some sort of placeholder, so I can specify the desired command in the markup of the actual `ListView`? This way, I can create more `ListView`s with this style, but executing different commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround -  Set the `Tag` of `ListView` to the actual command and then bind to the `Tag` property of `ListView` from `Button`.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Button Command="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
    ........
</DataTemplate>
```

and in `ListView`:

```
<ListView Tag="{Binding MyCommandOne}"/>
```